# How to show favorite project using pivot in vue and laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pivot, favorites

This is the all projects, and favorite button to show the favorite project only:

[image]

This is how I show all project:

```
<project v-for="(project, index) in projects" :key="project.id" :index="index" :details="project"></project>
```

This is the button favorite method:

```
toggleFavorite () {
  this.favoriteShown = !this.favoriteShown
  this.allProjectShown = !this.allProjectShown
},
```

I import the project from the other vue file

```
import project from './project'
```

And this is the whole favorite method in project.vue
[image]

And maybe you need to see the project.vue export default:

[image]

So, what should I add in this code to show the favorite projects only

```
<project v-for="(project, index) in projects" :key="project.id" :index="index" :details="project"></project>
```

Comment: Define a `computed`  property that returns just the projects that have `favorite: true` and use that in place of `projects`.

Comment: @Peppermintology can you show me how to code it?

Answer (score 0):

Define a computed property that filters your `projects` returning just the objects that have a `true` value for the `favorite` property.

I'm making some assumptions regarding the structure of your `project` object, however, the principle will remain the same.

An example of how you could filter results below:

```
let projects = [
    {
    id: 1,
    favorite: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    favorite: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    favorite: false
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    favorite: true
  }
];

let filteredProjects = projects.filter(p => p.favorite);
```

Obviously, you're not using a static array as I have in the example so you will need to alter it for your use case (e.g. `state.projects.filter(p => p.favorite)`). You could also use [lodash filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter) if you're already using that library.